# impersonate a user at runtime for spring hadoop configuration

Tags: spring, hadoop, spring-data

I have an web application that an receive requests for several other applications running from linux command line as from different users. For each of these requests I have to read data from hdfs for calling application folder which only the calling application linux user access to. Is there a way I can setup configuration in such a way that it can be overridden at run time to impersonate the caller application user for spring-hadoop kerberos authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.createProxyUser("user", UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser());
    ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void run() throws Exception {
            fsh.cp(file.getSourceFilePath(), destPathWithFileName);
            return null;
        }
    });
```